# Thread pools and stopping execution of a for loop when a counter reaches X

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I'm a bit confused with thread pools and providing an exit condition from a for loop.  I haven't found a decent explanation yet on how to do it properly.  I have been experimenting with a few possibilities but I'm stuck

I have this piece of code.

```
  @Override
  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
  public void auditAllDomainConfigurationStatuses() {
    logger.info("Starting audit of all domain configuration statusses");
    int errorStatusCounter = 0;
    Map<SubdomainRegistryStatus, List<String>> domainsByStatus = new HashMap<SubdomainRegistryStatus, List<String>>();
    List<DomainConfigurationStatus> domains = domainConfigurationStatusDao.findAll();
    for (DomainConfigurationStatus domainConfigurationStatus : domains) {
      String domainName = domainConfigurationStatus.getDomainName();      
      DomainConfigurationStatus result = domainConfigurationStatusAuditor.auditDomainConfigurationStatus(domainConfigurationStatus.getId());
      addDomainToDomainsByStatusMap(domainsByStatus, result, domainName);
      if(SubdomainRegistryStatus.ERROR.equals(result.getStatus())){
        errorStatusCounter++;
        if(errorStatusCounter >= EMERGENCY_AUDIT_STOP_LIMIT){
          logger.error("Emergency audit stop more then " + EMERGENCY_AUDIT_STOP_LIMIT + " records went into status ERROR");
          mailEmergencyDomainConfigurationStatusAuditStop();
          return;
        }
      }else{
        errorStatusCounter = 0;
      }      
    }

    mailDomainConfigurationStatusReport(domainsByStatus);
    logger.info("Audit of all domain configuration statusses completed");    
  }
```

This code will somewhere call the dns of a domain to fetch it's ip.  Then it will update a status in the database.  Quite a simple thing.  However business wants us to stop the entire process if X times after each other the status translated to ERROR.  I managed to write this , quite simple with the above method.  However the call to the dns to fetch the ip is slow, I can process about 6 domains per second.  We have to process over 32 000 domains.  We need to get performance up and for this multithreading is advicable.

So I started with progamming a task, creating a threadpool in spring etc...  Then I realized wait that EMERGENCY_AUDIT_STOP_LIMIT how can I still do this if the counter runs over multiple threads ...  Without any callback.  So I tried with a Callable instead of Runnable so I was working with a Future, then I came to the conclusion WTH am I thinking, the future will block on it's future.get() method so all I'm going to end up with is a method just as slow or slower then my original implementation.

So this was my road sofar and I'm now a bit blocked, a Runnable can't throw an exception so passing the counter to the task won't work either and a Callable will block so that's no option either.

If any multithreading guru has an idea I would be very grateful.  Below was my latest attempt , it wasn't broken but just as slow as my above method.

```
  @Override
  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
  public void auditAllDomainConfigurationStatuses() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    logger.info("Starting audit of all domain configuration statusses");
    int errorStatusCounter = 0;
    Map<SubdomainRegistryStatus, List<String>> domainsByStatus = new HashMap<SubdomainRegistryStatus, List<String>>();
    List<DomainConfigurationStatus> domains = domainConfigurationStatusDao.findAll();

    for (DomainConfigurationStatus domainConfigurationStatus : domains) {      
      try {
        Future<Integer> futureResult = taskExecutor.submit(new DomainConfigurationAuditTask(errorStatusCounter, domainConfigurationStatusAuditor, domainConfigurationStatus.getId(), domainsByStatus, EMERGENCY_AUDIT_STOP_LIMIT));
        futureResult.get();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Emergency audit stop more then " + EMERGENCY_AUDIT_STOP_LIMIT + " records went into status ERROR");
        mailEmergencyDomainConfigurationStatusAuditStop();
        return;
      }            
    }

    mailDomainConfigurationStatusReport(domainsByStatus);
    logger.info("Audit of all domain configuration statusses completed");    
  }
```

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: No our softwarestack is java 7 and will be for the next few years , our company is cautious upgrading java versions due to legacy applications

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a framework like Hystrix: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple solution.  Basically, the tasks for doing some work (i.e. DNS lookup) is completely isolated and parallelizable.  Part of it's work after a success or failure is to submit a success boolean to another `ExecutoService` with a *fixed size of 1*, which can do whatever error condition checking you want.

In this case, it's simply incrementing an integer with consecutive errors, until a max condition is reached and then sets an error condition which the work threads (DNS lookups) all check first for a fail-fast approach, so all queued up tasks will exit quickly after the error condition is met.

This ends up being pretty simple way for tracking *consecutive* errors in a multi-threaded scenario like this, as you're single-threading a check on the responses

I can think of a much more elegant solution using Java 8's `CompletableFuture`, but sounds like that is off the table

```
package so.thread.errcondition;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main {

  public static Random rand = new Random();

  public static ExecutorService workers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

  // NOTE, this executor has a FIXED size of 1 for in-order processing
  public static ExecutorService watcher = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

  public static AtomicBoolean errorCondition = new AtomicBoolean(false);
  public static AtomicInteger errorCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

  public static Integer MAX_ERRORS = 5;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    int jobs = 1000;

    for (int i = 0; i < jobs; i++) {
      workers.submit(getWork());
    }

    Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));

  }

  // parallelizable task, the number of parallel workers is irrelevant
  public static Runnable getWork() {
    return new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

        // fail fast
        if (errorCondition.get()) {
          System.out.println("%%% MAX_ERRORS of [" + MAX_ERRORS + "] occurred, skipping task");
          return;
        }
        // do work
        if (rand.nextBoolean()) {
          // GOOD JOB
          System.out.println("+++ GOOD RESULT");
          submitDoneTask(true);
        } else {
          // ERROR
          System.out.println("*** BAD RESULT");
          submitDoneTask(false);
        }
      }
    };
  }

  public static void submitDoneTask(final boolean success) {
    watcher.submit(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        if (!errorCondition.get() && success) {
          errorCount.set(0);
        } else {
          int errors = errorCount.incrementAndGet();
          if (errors >= MAX_ERRORS) {
            errorCondition.set(true);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice very creative, I was working on a bit of a similar track, while you posted this however I wouldn't have thought to use two ExecutorService.  I'll give it a spin with the full code